# Lorentz transformation of fields in Srednicki

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, metric-tensor, conventions

In Mark Srednicki's QFT book, he writes in the Heisenberg picture:
$$e^{\frac{iHt}{\hbar}}\varphi(\vec x,0)e^{-\frac{iHt}{\hbar}}=\varphi(\vec x,t)$$
This is quite reasonable, because I can view $\varphi$  as an operator depending on coordinates (Is that correct?)

But the author then makes a relativistic generalization:
$$e^{-\frac{iPx}{\hbar}}\varphi(0)e^{\frac{iPx}{\hbar}}=\varphi(x)$$
where $Px=P^{\mu}x_{\mu}=\vec P\cdot\vec x-Hct$

But I'm much confused why is it true for spatial part, since $e^{-\frac{i\vec P\cdot \vec x}{\hbar}}$ is spatial translation operator, as $e^{-\frac{iHt}{\hbar}}$ is time translation operator, they should appear with the same sign in $4$-vector form, which contradicts Srednicki's generalization.

What's wrong with my reasoning? Or is this an error of Sredinicki's book?

Comment: Does Srednicki explicitly state that the second equation is a generalization of the first?

Comment: Yes. In section 2.